# Having trouble with Ajax jQuery JSON script

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm using the following script to send some form values to a script on our network to return a json object:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sitesearch").click(function (event) {
        var url = 'http://192.168.1.75/search/index.php'

        var q = $("#q").val();
        var v = $("#v").val();
        var h = $("#h").val();
        var c = $("#c").val();

        var data = "q="+q+"&v="+v+"&h="+h+"&c="+c;

        var totalurl = url+"?"+data;

        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json){
                alert('Success');
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Fail');
            }
        });

        $('#response').append(totalurl);
    });
});
```

Everytime I call the script it returns a fail message. I'm sure I'm not seeing the wood for the trees but i can't for the life of me see what's wrong. Any help gratefully received.

Comment: if the script/service is on your own domain, why do you need to use JSONP?  Why not an AJAX call and have the PHP script return JSON?  To debug though, you should be able to use your browsers developer tools to see the outgoing request and the corresponding request, and look at the response headers/body for possible errors.

Comment: @thescientist The OP might be testing locally, but the end use case may require JSONP. IMO, the issue is happening on the server side, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Modify the error function like this: `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus + errorThrown);
} ` and check what error you are actually getting...

Comment: The service is on a different server hence JSONP.

Comment: @PalashMondal - I've added the error checking function you suggest and get the following output: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://192.168.1.75/search/index.php?callback=jQuery18109067658667918295_1355327677088&q=&v=&h=&c=&_=1355327684266". jquery.js:8169
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : index.php:1
parsererrorError: jQuery18109067658667918295_1355327677088 was not called

Comment: @matt: It seems your server isn't correctly outputting JSONP.  What is it outputting?  It is wrapping the object in the value of `$_GET['jsoncallback']`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - I think you're right - it's outputting JSON rather than jsonp. Example output: {"start_reindex":1,"index":"Using \/tmp\/index1","result":[{"title":"Tes ttes tes ","link":"\/blogs\/1\/testtest","summary":"testset ","headset":":mjizntmo:","version":":zthkyzan::nzaxndjm:","category":":ngmxnfhz:"}]} - which validates as json. Is there anything I can do without haviong access to the service script?

Comment: @matt: The server has to support JSONP, if it doesn't, you're out of luck.  Also, why are you setting `jsonp: "jsoncallback"`?  Maybe the server uses a different key for the callback name?

Comment: @RocketHazmat- Sorry the jsonp:"jsoncallback" was an error - have edited now.

Comment: @matt: Does it work now that you removed that?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Unfortunately no!

Comment: @matt: My guess is the server doesn't support JSONP, or it does and you're not sending the correct callback key.

Answer (score 0):

Your **data** is not json, it is a querystring.  Also, you do not specify if it is a **POST** or **GET**. Your json most likely should look like this?

```
var data = {
    "q": $("#q").val(),
    "v": $("#v").val(),
    "h": $("#h").val(),
    "c": $("#c").val(),
};
```

Comment: Urgh, please read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) before answering. `data` _can_ be a query string and "It is converted to a query string, if not already a string." If no request type is specified, the `$.ajax()` call defaults to using GET.

Comment: I said *you* did not specify if it was a GET or POST.  And I did not know about the querystring, my apologies, sorry for trying to help - try not to be a dick.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's specified or not; it'll just use GET. I'm not trying to be any kind of phallus, but simply bringing valid points to against your question.

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a JavaScript object, nothing to do with JSON.  The `data` param can either be a query string or an object (that will be converted to a query string).

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I finally adopted was to make an ajax call to a php script on the local server, then used file_get_contents to return the json from the web service. Bit of a hack but we're against the clock and it works!!